MissingPlugin Exception Calling native code with methodChannel in Firebase.onBackGroundMessage
Im trying to make a call to a native method when a notification arrives in the background, but when flutter tries to make the call to the native method, i get this error:
Error
I/flutter (20709): Executing background
E/flutter (20709): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method triggerAlarm on channel com.channel/method)
E/flutter (20709): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:332:7)
E/flutter (20709): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (20709): #1      AlarmService.triggerAlarm (package:alarm_example/main.dart:49:7)
E/flutter (20709): <asynchronous suspension>

These are my kotlin files to setup the method:
Application.kt
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeFlutterEngine()
    }

    private fun initializeFlutterEngine() {
        // Create a new FlutterEngine instance
        val flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)

        flutterEngine.dartExecutor.executeDartEntrypoint(
            DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
        )
        // Cache the engine for later use
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("my_engine_id", flutterEngine)
    }
}

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    private val METHOD_CHANNEL = "com.channel/method"
    private val engineId = "my_engine_id"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Creating main activity")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put(engineId, flutterEngine)

        // Initialize and cache the FlutterEngine
        // Get the cached FlutterEngine
        val cachedEngine = FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(engineId)
        if (cachedEngine != null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Using cached FlutterEngine $cachedEngine")
            configureFlutterEngine(cachedEngine)
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Cached FlutterEngine not found")
        }
    }

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        flutterEngine.plugins.add(AlarmPlugin()) 
    }
}


AlarmPlugin.kt
class AlarmPlugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler, ActivityAware {

    private lateinit var context: Context
    private var methodChannel: MethodChannel? = null

    // Instance variable for FlutterPluginBinding
    private var flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding? = null

    override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        flutterPluginBinding = binding

        if(methodChannel == null){
            Log.d("PLUGIN", "Initializing flutter plugin first time")
            // Init Flutter Plugin First Time Only
            initPlugin(binding.binaryMessenger)
        }
    }

    private fun initPlugin(binaryMessenger: BinaryMessenger) {
        methodChannel = MethodChannel(binaryMessenger, "com.channel/method")
        methodChannel?.setMethodCallHandler(this)
    }

    override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
        flutterPluginBinding?.binaryMessenger?.let {
            Log.d("PLUGIN", "Reinitialize forcefully from MainIsolate")

            // Reinitialize MethodChannel Forcefully from MainIsolate
            initPlugin(it)
         }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivity() {
        methodChannel = null
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges() {
        // Handle configuration changes if needed
    }

    override fun onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {}

    override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
        // Clean up resources when detached from engine
        methodChannel = null
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        when (call.method) {
            "triggerAlarm" -> {
                Log.d("PLUGIN", "Calling Alarm")

                result.success("triggerAlarm done")
            }
            else -> {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }
}

And the call from the flutter side when the notification arrives in the background
main.dart
... 

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Executing background");

  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('com.channel/method');

  await _channel.invokeMethod('triggerAlarm');
}

Future<void> main() async { 
    ...

    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    ...

  runApp(const App());
}

...


I have tried flutter clean and rebuilding the apk, also ensured the name of the methods and channels are the same.
The method does work when called with the app opened, but it doesnt work in the background. Right now im just logging something when the method gets triggered.
Flutter Doctor:
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.23.0-13.0.pre.189, on Microsoft Windows [Versi¢n 10.0.22631.4317], locale es-ES)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 17.7.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.94.2)
[√] Connected device (4 available)
[√] Network resources

• No issues found!

Question:
How can i make sure my native method is setup in the channel when a notification arrives in the background?
I tried following this medium article but it didn't work as expected:
https://medium.com/@kkgowtham/workaround-for-method-channel-communication-breaking-when-background-message-handler
